# how insert anchor tags around a link inside a list item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to link the url from an API and I have tried just about everything I can think of but nothing seems to work. With all the use jQuery has I thought this topic would be covered more. I tried wrap, wrapInner, append, prepend etc.. what am I missing?

Here's the script:

edit:
I want to wrap the last list item in the loop   but not around the li , inside of it.

```
  <div class="content">

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({     
                url: "http://api.espn.com/v1/fantasy/football/news/?limit=15",
                data: {
                  // enter your developer api key here
                  apikey: "wqq7tafpp3ff7ba87ny85n67",
                  // the type of data you're expecting back from the api
                  _accept: "application/json"
                },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {

                 // create an unordered list of headlines
                  var ul = $('<div class="fball_group">');

                 // get headline, desription, and source text
                   $.each(data.headlines, function() {

                      var li = $('<div class="fball_hdline">').text(this.headline);
                      ul.append(li);

                      var li2 = $('<div class="fball_descrip">').text(this.description);
                      ul.append(li2);

                      var li3 = $('<div class="fball_src">').text(this.source);
                      ul.append(li3);


                      var li4 = $('<div      class="fball_links">').text(this.links.web.href);
                      ul.append(li4);



                    });

                  // append this list to the content div

                  $('.content').append(ul);

                },
                error: function() {
                   alert('There was an error processing the ESPN API');
                }
              });


            });
```

Comment: Silly question but are you sure `$('.content')` exists?

Comment: You really need to show your HTML as well. Better yet, put the JS and HTML on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: heres the page , sorry I forgot to add it, http://fantasyaficionado.com/news/

Comment: @MichaelHicks, please create a *reduced* test case of only the code that is causing an issue. I have no desire to sort through your entire site to solve your problems.

Comment: Isnt that the code I put up top in the main box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not understood very well what  you want 
 but 
you want make this a link

```
 var li4 = $('<li      class="fball_links">').text(this.links.web.href);
```

you simply create a  link tag

```
link=$("<a/>").setAttr('href',this.links.web.href).text("linkname");

 var li4 = $('<li      class="fball_links">').append(link);
 ul.append(li4);
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the text so I dont have that ugly link, just something like "Read Full Text"   ???

Comment: can i have more details please

Comment: The last list item in the loop i want to wrap but not around the li just the URL  , your on the right track I think...

Comment: you can not do it  because you are using <ul></ul> means that each child must be an <li> you can not just insert the link without <li>
instead you can use <div> and insert on it others <div> which in lieu of <li>  and at the end <a>

Comment: Oh so I can use <li> in a div and it will work? Doesnt seem very semantic but if thats what I have to do, it will have to work.I'll try that and let you know, thanks.

Comment: no what i have said is 
instead of   because it wont work 
<ul>
  <li></li>
  ....
   <a></a>
<ul>

<div class="fakeUL">
  <div class="fakeLI"></div>
  .....
   <a></a>

</div>

Comment: Oh, so your saying just use all Divs?

Comment: yes because  what you want to do can not be accomplished by <ul> because it has  certain rule that must be respected in doctype 
 and you can decorate the div  to be just like li ^_^

Comment: I cant get your code to work still though... I tried wrapperInner at the end and that worked but the URL is still linking to a hashtag. Im not sure what to do, this shouldnt be this hard.

Comment: I fix it and edited your code to the right one but they must be still approving the edit. It ended up looking like this, its not perfect but it works.  var li4 = $(li3).append("<a href=" + this.links.web.href + " target=\"_blank\">Read Full Story</a>");
                          ul.append(li4);